# Segfault when initializing 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I cannot find what's wrong in this simple array initialization.
The program crashes with a segfault on `field[x][y] = ' ';`, x and y at 0 (I use Code::Blocks debugger)

```
/* init data structures */
char **field;
int field_width=5,field_height=5;
field = malloc(sizeof(char*)*field_width);
for(x=0;x<field_width;x++)
{
    field[x] = malloc(sizeof(char)*field_height);
    for(y=0;y<field_height;y++)
    {
        field[x][y] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: This code snippet doesn't crash for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually simplified the code snippet. `field_width` was not initialzed. I'm surprised this did not raise a warning during the build. And I don't really know why it generates a segfault when x=0.

But my problem is solved. Thank you all and sorry for the conveniance...

Comment: With an uninitialised `field_width`, that could have happened to have a large value, so that the `malloc` failed. Did you check the return value of `malloc` in the real code?

Comment: I didn't check. Following your advice I did, and indeed, that is what failed. Thanks for the advice. Another good habit I have to remember!

Answer (score 1):

```
field = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*)*field_width);
```

The `char*` cast maybe?

Comment: In (ANSI) C, there is no need to cast the result of malloc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Unlike C++, you don't need to explicitly cast from `void*` to another pointer in C.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be this?

```
field = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*field_width);
```

**Edit**

`malloc` can return null, so it would pay to check that `field[x] = malloc(sizeof(char)*field_height);` block of memory is valid.

Comment: Unlike C++, you don't need to explicitly cast from `void*` to another pointer in C.

Answer (score 0):

Before you initialized `field_width`, it probably contained random data.  Using `field_width` in the `malloc` statement then [triggered undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c).  The compiler could do whatever it wanted, from skipping the `malloc` to using whatever garbage happened to be stored in `field_width`, or even worse/stranger things!.  Regardless, you were unlikely to get the `malloc` call you wanted, and either if it didn't run or returned `NULL` (e.g. if `field_width` contained a value that was too large to be `malloc`ed), the resulting value of `field` was unlikely to point to valid memory.  This would then cause a segfault when you dereference `field` in the loop.  You were fortunate that you got such a clear sign that something was wrong -- memory errors aren't always so blatant.